# YuMi RobotModel no transform from [link1] to [link2]

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to move ABB YuMi IRB14000 using MoveIt with the new [abb_robot_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver), luckily there is a [modified robot description](https://github.com/robberthofmanfm/yumi/tree/egm_modifications/yumi_description) that is supposed to work with the new driver. but when I'm trying to use that I get the following Errors:

[image: image description]

Can you please tell me how to solve that please? here is the generated [SRDF](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/yumi_egm_driver/blob/main/yumi/yumi_moveit_config/config/yumi.srdf) file that I'm using, and this is the [launch](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/yumi_egm_driver/blob/main/yumi/yumi_moveit_config/launch/moveit_planning_execution.launch) file that I'm using.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391430/yumi-robotmodel-no-transform-from-%5Blink1%5D-to-%5Blink2%5D/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-11-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-22**:
Would it be possible to show the frames tree by using:

`rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py` and to save the pdf `evince frames.pdf`

I took a look at your robot description, looks ok, but before going that rabbit hole, let's check if transforms are working.

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-11-22**:
@osilva, thanks for your response, here is the [frames tree](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/yumi_egm_driver/blob/main/yumi/yumi_description/urdf/frames.pdf).

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-22**:
Thank you. Yes the gripper fingers are not connected as you can see in frames tree. Let me take a look why.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-22**:
I think the abb driver sdrf only looks for the standard 14 links (7left, 7 right) as technically you could attach any type of grippers which makes sense:
https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver/blob/master/abb_robot_bringup_examples/config/ex3_hardware_egm.yaml

But your grippers need to publish as well so I am thinking you need to do this separately by adding to this section in the launch file.

```
  <!-- Non-standard joint names:
       - Create a file [robot_moveit_config]/config/joint_names.yaml
           controller_joint_names: [joint_1, joint_2, ... joint_N] 
       - Update with joint names for your robot (in order expected by rbt controller)
       - and uncomment the following line: -->
  <!-- osparam command="load" file="$(find abb_irb1200_support)/config/joint_names_irb1200_7_70.yaml" / -->
```

https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/yumi_egm_driver/blob/main/yumi/yumi_moveit_config/launch/moveit_planning_execution.launch

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-11-25**:
@osilva the problem turns to be that the grippers joints were not publishing, remapping

`<node name="yumi_joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" > <rosparam param="source_list">["/yumi/rws/joint_states"]</rosparam>  </node>`

published `0.0` values for the grippers joints, and hence the RobotModel stopped to parse the errors (even though grippers joints positions are `0.0` which is not the actual position), but still the MotionPlanning module parsing a warning `Requesting initial scene failed`!

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-25**:
Partial solution but great progress.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-26**:
@bhomaidan I will suggest to document your work as an answer. I understand you still have a warning error, but others will benefit from your efforts. Thank you.

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-11-26**:
@osilva I will try to do it soon with a minimal working example, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@osilva These settings have worked in my case:

`ros_controllers.yaml`:

```
# Simulation settings for using moveit_sim_controllers
moveit_sim_hw_interface:
  joint_model_group: todo_group_name
  joint_model_group_pose: todo_state_name
# Settings for ros_control_boilerplate control loop
generic_hw_control_loop:
  loop_hz: 300
  cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01
# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
  joints:
    - yumi_robl_joint_1
    - yumi_robl_joint_2
    - yumi_robl_joint_3
    - yumi_robl_joint_4
    - yumi_robl_joint_5
    - yumi_robl_joint_6
    - yumi_robl_joint_7
    - yumi_robr_joint_1
    - yumi_robr_joint_2
    - yumi_robr_joint_3
    - yumi_robr_joint_4
    - yumi_robr_joint_5
    - yumi_robr_joint_6
    - yumi_robr_joint_7
  sim_control_mode: 1  # 0: position, 1: velocity
# Publish all joint states
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50

controller_list:
  - name: /yumi/egm/jnt_traj_vel_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - yumi_robl_joint_1
      - yumi_robl_joint_2
      - yumi_robl_joint_3
      - yumi_robl_joint_4
      - yumi_robl_joint_5
      - yumi_robl_joint_6
      - yumi_robl_joint_7
      - yumi_robr_joint_1
      - yumi_robr_joint_2
      - yumi_robr_joint_3
      - yumi_robr_joint_4
      - yumi_robr_joint_5
      - yumi_robr_joint_6
      - yumi_robr_joint_7
```

`controllers.yaml`:

```
controller_list:
  - name: /yumi/egm/jnt_traj_vel_controller
    action_ns: joint_trajectory_action
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - yumi_robl_joint_1
      - yumi_robl_joint_2
      - yumi_robl_joint_3
      - yumi_robl_joint_4
      - yumi_robl_joint_5
      - yumi_robl_joint_6
      - yumi_robl_joint_7
      - yumi_robr_joint_1
      - yumi_robr_joint_2
      - yumi_robr_joint_3
      - yumi_robr_joint_4
      - yumi_robr_joint_5
      - yumi_robr_joint_6
      - yumi_robr_joint_7
```

`ex3_controllers.yaml`

```
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 250

egm_state_controller:
  type         : abb_egm_state_controller/EGMStateController
  publish_rate : 250

jnt_traj_vel_controller:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - yumi_robl_joint_1
    - yumi_robl_joint_2
    - yumi_robl_joint_3
    - yumi_robl_joint_4
    - yumi_robl_joint_5
    - yumi_robl_joint_6
    - yumi_robl_joint_7
    - yumi_robr_joint_1
    - yumi_robr_joint_2
    - yumi_robr_joint_3
    - yumi_robr_joint_4
    - yumi_robr_joint_5
    - yumi_robr_joint_6
    - yumi_robr_joint_7
  constraints:
    stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0
  gains:
    yumi_robl_joint_1: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robl_joint_2: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robl_joint_3: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robl_joint_4: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robl_joint_5: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robl_joint_6: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robl_joint_7: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robr_joint_1: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robr_joint_2: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robr_joint_3: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robr_joint_4: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robr_joint_5: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robr_joint_6: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
    yumi_robr_joint_7: {p: 1.0, i: 0, d: 0.00, i_clamp: 0.1}
```

and changed the default controller in the bringup example launch file to be:

`<node pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" name="stopped" args="--stopped jnt_traj_vel_controller"/>`
as it is compatible with MoveIt.

Note that each time you want to execute a motion using MoveIt, you have to start EGM joint:
`rosservice call /yumi/rws/sm_addin/start_egm_joint "{}"`, and then switch the controller:

```
rosservice call /yumi/egm/controller_manager/switch_controller "start_controllers: [jnt_traj_vel_controller]
stop_controllers: ['']
strictness: 1
start_asap: false
timeout: 0.0"
```

And you should get: `ok: True`

Finally, here is my `moveit_planning_execution.launch`

```
<launch>
  <!-- The planning and execution components of MoveIt! configured to run -->

  <!-- the "sim" argument controls whether we connect to a Simulated or Real robot -->
  <!--  - if sim=false, a robot_ip argument is required -->
  <arg name="sim" default="false" doc="Use industrial robot simulator instead of real robot" />
  <arg name="robot_ip" unless="$(arg sim)" value="192.168.125.1" doc="IP of controller (only required if not using industrial simulator)" />

  <!-- By default, we do not start a database (it can be large) -->
  <arg name="db" default="false" doc="Start the MoveIt database" />
  <!-- Allow user to specify database location -->
  <arg name="db_path" default="$(find yumi_moveit_config)/default_warehouse_mongo_db" doc="Path to database files" />

  <!-- load the robot_description parameter before launching ROS-I nodes -->
  <include file="$(find yumi_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
  </include>

  <!-- run the robot simulator and action interface nodes -->
  <group if="$(arg sim)">
    <include file="$(find industrial_robot_simulator)/launch/robot_interface_simulator.launch" />
  </group>

  <!-- run the "real robot" interface nodes -->
  <!--   - this typically includes: robot_state, motion_interface, and joint_trajectory_action nodes -->
  <!--   - replace these calls with appropriate robot-specific calls or launch files -->
  <group unless="$(arg sim)">
    <include file="$(find abb_robot_bringup_examples)/launch/ex3_rws_and_egm_yumi_robot.launch" >
      <arg name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>
    </include>
  </group>

  <!-- , "/yumi/gripper_states" -->
  <!-- Joint state and robot state publisher calls -->
  <node name="yumi_joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" >
    <rosparam param="source_list">["/yumi/rws/joint_states"]</rosparam> 
  </node>

  <!-- publish the robot state (tf transforms) -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

  <include file="$(find yumi_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
  </include>

  <include file="$(find yumi_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <!-- If database loading was enabled, start mongodb as well -->
  <include file="$(find yumi_moveit_config)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" if="$(arg db)">
    <arg name="moveit_warehouse_database_path" value="$(arg db_path)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) with karma: 114 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-29**:
Thank you for documenting your efforts in this answer that others will benefit in the future.